# php Carbon set Locale for input

Tags: php, php-carbon

I need to turn multilingual date strings into carbon instances:

English works fine:

```
new Carbon('December 2018');
```

But it fails with other languages as input:

```
new Carbon('Dezember 2018');
```

I can set the locale for outputs like diffForHumans(), but I have not found a way to do it for the input string.

```
    Carbon::setLocale('de');
    new Carbon('Dezember 2018');
```

does not work either. Throws:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Dezember 2018) at position 0 (D): The time  
  zone could not be found in the database
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **createFromFormat**

```
Carbon::setLocale('de');
Carbon::createFromFormat("F Y", "Dezember 2018");
```

Comment: Throws:  A textual month could not be found